# How to Connect to MySQL Database hosted on Raspberry Pi from Excel on LAN

Tags: mysql, database, excel, raspberry-pi

I have a MySQL database hosted on a raspberry pi, IP:192.168.100.230.  I have a user on there called `'excelUser'@'192.168.100.210'` with all privileges granted. I have a database called `pythonProg` and a table within called `pidRun`.  I can log in fine locally.  I have a Windows machine on the LAN, IP:192.168.100.210, my intention is to connect to the database from Excel (2013 if it matters).  I have altered the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to read: `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` no other changes have been made.

When I try to connect from the Excel Data Connection Wizard, I enter the server name of 192.168.100.230:3306 and the User Name: excelUser with Password: password123.  I receive the error:

`[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.`

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Update: I have installed the MySQL Excel Extension and it connects / imports fine.  It still won't connect using the Excel built in connector.

Comment: Did you try connecting with some other tool to try and isolate the problem?

Comment: Hi, I'm quite new to this.  Any idea of a suitable tool to use?

Comment: The [official Workbench tool](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is a good place to start.